# User Agent Stylesheet - css property for strong is disabled?

Tags: html, css

[image: strong issue in user agent stylesheet]
In my [codepen](http://codepen.io/KerryRuddock/pen/VpVLEo?editors=1100) I placed `<strong></strong>` tags within a paragraph, but I noticed no emphasis being displayed.  Chrome developer tools shows the user agent stylesheet for strong has a line through it.  What could possibly be disabling this setting as I do not override strong myself or change any font-weight within my code?

I am using chrome version 56.

```
<p id="p10">offset() - Get the current coordinates of the first element, or set the coordinates of every element, in the set of matched elements, relative to the document. <strong>[returns: object]</strong>
</p>
```

Comment: You're using a reset.css file.

Comment: Thank you,  I guess I am missing something here. Why would the reset.css file which contains: font: inherit override the font-weight?   Doesn't inherit mean take it from the parent or my case the user agent stylesheet?.  If using a reset.css will always override <strong> tags perhaps reset.css should be the file that redefines <strong> back to its original intentions.

Comment: @Eggs `inherit` means use the same property as the parent element. And what you need is a _normalize_ stylesheet rather than a _reset_ stylesheet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is it possible that you are setting the `font-weight` or calling `font: inherit` on the `<p>` tag or possibly from the id?

As other answers have stated, you are probably overwriting this in your css reset file:
`https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/meyer-reset/2.0/reset.min.css`

You could redeclare it as follows:

```
strong { 
   font-weight: bold !important;
}
```

Comment: If I want to use a reset.css this is what I will have to do.

Comment: If you redeclare it after including the reset one, there is no need tor !important.

Answer (score 4):

Your codepen calls this reset stylesheet (the classic "Eric Meyer Reset"):

```
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/meyer-reset/2.0/reset.min.css
```

This resets *all* internal browser styles (i.e. it overwrites them), so you have (among many others) to add your own CSS for the `strong` tag with a rule like

```
strong {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

Or you just erase the reference to that reset style sheet...

Just as a reaction to the downvote: what do you think this is:

[image]

Comment: Yep. that reset.css is the problem.  Not my downvote. +1 from me.

Answer (score -1):

> Is it possible that you are setting the font-weight or calling font: inherit on the
>
> tag or possibly from the id? I think that might be overwriting the  tag. You could redeclare it as follows:
>
> `strong { font-weight: bold; }`

If the above solution does not work, try using it with `!important`, like this:

`strong { font-weight: bold !important; }`

Comment: Don't know who gave you your original downvote?  You supplied the same correct answer as Tony.